# Plot data at coordinates lat, lon using matplotlib and basemap

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I collect data about things like water temperature, air temperature, humidity etc. in a csv-file, and I want to plot that data on a map. However, I run into issues when trying to plot it, since latitudes, longitudes and data lists are one-dimentional. Therefore I cannot use pcolormesh over the map. I've tried googling how to do this, but I haven't been able to find a way that works for me.

The problem is not with `basemap`, but with finding a way to plot data where, e.g. a low temperature results in a blue color at the recorded coordinates, while a high temperature results in a red color so I get a map similar to this.
[image: Temperature plot of USA]

Ideally I'd want a function that looks like `plot(latitudes, longitudes, data)` where all three variables are just lists. I don't think this exists though.

Data in the csv-file is represented like this:

```
Date,Time,Latitude,Longitude,WaterTemp,AirTemp,Humidity
211222,14042300,60.438760,5.310859,5.2,2.4,0.21
```

So how would I convert the data to be able to do this?

I've tried to use `pcolormesh` but reshaped the data lists, but I haven't gotten that to work. The `meshgrid` function doesn't fix the problem either. Every way I've tried to plot the data has resulted in different errors, like "shapes don't match" or "data must be two-dimentional". I can use `map.scatter(lats, lons, latlon=True)`. However that doesn't let me set each scatter point with a value, just the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try interpolation to create a regular grid based on your data.

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lat = np.random.randint(-40, 40, 1000)
lon = np.random.randint(-40, 40, 1000)
temp = np.random.randint(0, 32, 1000)

spline_2d = sp.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(lat, lon, temp)

lat_min = np.min(lat)
lat_max = np.max(lat)

lon_min = np.min(lon)
lon_max = np.max(lon)

grid_points = 100

lat_grid = np.arange(lat_min, lat_max, (lat_max - lat_min)/grid_points)
lon_grid = np.arange(lon_min, lon_max, (lon_max - lon_min)/grid_points)

lat_grid, lon_grid = np.meshgrid(lat_grid, lon_grid, indexing = 'ij')

interp_points = spline_2d.ev(lat_grid.ravel(), lon_grid.ravel()).reshape((grid_points, grid_points))

plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(lat_grid, lon_grid, interp_points)
```

Comment: Hmm apparently scipy doesn't have attribute 'interpolate'.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\johan\Documents\Programming\Python\Exercises\Python\matplotlib exercises\plot.py", line 9, in <module>
    spline_2d = sp.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(lat, lon, temp)
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'interpolate'`

Comment: Try `from scipy.interpolate import SmoothBivariateSpline` and then drop the `sp.interpolate.` from the `spline_2d` line.

Comment: I get the error/warning `C:\Users\johan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_fitpack2.py:1176: UserWarning: 
The required storage space exceeds the available storage space: nxest
or nyest too small, or s too small.
The weighted least-squares spline corresponds to the current set of
knots.
  warnings.warn(message)` What does this error mean?

Comment: Unsure, but you can try adjusting some of the parameters in the BivariateSpline and see if that fixes the warning. Alternatively, it shouldn't prevent you from performing the interpolation. If the output plot seems reasonable, you can consider just ignoring the warning.

Comment: It seemingly work. But If I for example say `lat = [i for i in range(100)]
lon = [i for i in range(100)]
temp = [5 for i in range(100)]` it doesn't produce the same color for each pixel even though the temp is the same, which is what I want.

Comment: Since you're only defining the temp along a diagonal line, it's not entirely unreasonable for it to to model a decay in temperature further away from the line of points. It depends on the interpolation model. You can get something more constant if you set the `kx` and `ky` parameters to 1.

Comment: In general, interpolation is not going to work very well if your data points are very sparse compared to the area of the grid you're interpolating over.

Comment: Sure I get that. But in my dataset, each specific coordinate (every row) has one temperature value assigned to it. Are there any methods to rather plot the datapoints then? Also, not every point on the map is going to have a value assigned to it, where for example the data is collected only through a curvy river.

Comment: If you want just the data points, you can just use `plt.scatter(lat, lon, c = temp, cmap = 'coolwarm')`.